# Can this multithreading program work correctly on an one-core processor?

Tags: c#, multithreading

This program parses text file. It has two threads. One of them reads file, another parses file. Can this multithreading program work correctly on an one-core processor? I added the waiting of thread ending before another thread creating in order to get correct work on an one-core processor.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace lab2Form
{ 
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private CLogParser m_parser;
        private Thread m_parserThread, m_fileReaderThread;


        public Form1(string logName)
        {           
            InitializeComponent();  
            m_parser = new CLogParser();                
            timer1.Interval = 50;

            m_fileReaderThread = new Thread(m_parser.ThreadReadList);
            m_fileReaderThread.Start(logName);

            m_fileReaderThread.Join(); THE ADDED STRING

            m_parserThread = new Thread(m_parser.ThreadProc);
            m_parserThread.Start(); 

            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (m_parserThread.ThreadState != ThreadState.Stopped)
            {
                m_parser.ShowData(ref dmRequestsGridView, ref URLGridView, ref                      dmDataGridView, ref errorCodesGridView);
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("Parsing Complete!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I only have a task to get program, which will correct work on an one-core proccessor. And what about threads attaching to a core?

Comment: Haven't you tested it? What are the results?

Comment: Multiply variant and non-multiply variants work correctly in equal time. I haven't tested program on an one-core architecture and with attaching to one core.

Comment: What is the point of starting a thread to do A(), joining it, and then starting a thread to do B()?  Why not start just one thread that does A() and then B()?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. In general, you can happily run a process with more threads than physical processors - if anything, you run into more threading issues if you have multiple physical processor cores (as it is suddenly possibly for two (or more) things to happen in the same clock cycle.

Comment: Happily? .. The higher volume of context switches would make me sad not happy :(

Comment: Happy vs. unhappy depends on what the threads are doing.  You might not want to have more CPU-bound threads than you have cores, but computation is not the only reason to spawn threads.  The other reason for creating a thread is to wait for and handle some asynchronous event.  You might have dozens of such threads, quietly waiting for whatever it is they wait for while your compute thread(s) chew up the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-tasking operating systems have been around longer than multi-core architectures. The OS simply performs a context-switch between threads. Individual threads are not starved (well, they can be if you do something wrong, but in the simple case, they all get a time slice).

You do not need to call `fileReaderThread.Join()`